# How to disable contexte in a Spotify App (so previous/next buttons are disabled)

Tags: spotify

Someone ask the same question here. iKenndac answer it. But I need more details and I cannot find a way to add a comment to the question so I create a new question here.

I want to be able to control track played by spotify. So I want to disable previous and next button.

It seems that the solution is to play a track without giving a context to the player. I did it but next/previous are not disabled. Spotify act as the current context is my starred playlist.

Here is some code

```
var sp = getSpotifyApi(1);
var models = sp.require('sp://import/scripts/api/models');
var player = models.player;
var pl_starred = models.library.starredPlaylist;

exports.init = init;

function init() {
    var header = document.getElementById("header");
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*pl_starred.length)
    var track = pl_starred.get(index);

    if (pl_starred == null) {
        header.innerText = "starred not found";
    } else if (track == null) {
        header.innerHTML = "cannot get track from starred";
    } else {
        header.innerHTML = "starred " + index + "/" + pl_starred.length + " : " + track.name;
    }

    player.play(track,null);
}
```

**Edit: some new test after the answer from iKenndac**

I try to separate the track from its context but it does not work.
So I try to load a track using an hardcoded URI. So I did not load the starred playlist. But it did not work too

Here my code

```
function init() {

    var header = document.getElementById("header");

    var player = models.player;

    models.Track.fromURI("spotify:track:3ZfW4Z3MEvd82pv5J0rN2l", function(trackNotInStarred) {
        console.log("Track loaded", trackNotInStarred.name);
        player.play(trackNotInStarred, null);
        header.innerHTML = "starred: " + trackNotInStarred.name;
    }); 
}
```

**New edit**: in fact the previous/next button are not disable but if I click on previous it restart the track and next it jump to a "no track" state and then previous/play/next are disabled.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's inferring the context from the fact you got the track from the Starred playlist to start with.

Try this to separate the track from the context:

```
var player = models.player;
var trackInStarred = pl_starred.get(index);

models.Track.fromURI(trackInStarred.uri, function(trackNotInStarred) {
    console.log("Track loaded", trackNotInStarred.name);
    player.play(trackNotInStarred, null);
});
```

Comment: Thanks again for the quick answer. I might have missed something as previous/next button still available. And the context is again the starred playlist. I will first try to load the track without getting it from the starred playlist but using an hardcoded uri to test.